# ask(Alexa Skill Kit) cli asks for authorization code all the time

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My requirement is to automate skill create and ask deploy via pipelines for which I am relying on *ask cli*

I am using this [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/manage-credentials-with-ask-cli.html#ask-cli-env-vars) to set the envionment variables and using curl to get the access token which I then set as "ASK_ACCESS_TOKEN".

I am also aware that to get the refreshtoken, you need to provide the "Authorization code" via cli "ask generate-lwa-token --no-browser" command.

The refresh token is valid for 1 hour and I provide this refresh token as an input to my pipeline each time it gets expired.

However what I am noticing is that the refresh token even though it is expected to be valid for an hour, throws a 400 bad request the SECOND time I run the pipeline.

If I generate a new refresh token and input it, all works fine?